# JS menu, close menu on menu click

Tags: javascript, menu

i am trying to create a menu with JS, when i click on the first menu item and it is open, then i want when i click on the next item i want the first one to close and the second one to open and when i am clicking on the open menu item i want it to close. also when i click anywhere if i can make it close as well... 
here the code i have 
HTML

```
<div class="container-header">
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a onclick="dropdownToggle(event)"><span>Products</span></a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <ul class="submenu-img">
            <li><a><img src="2015_images/img.png">title</a></li>
            <li><a><img src="2015_images/img.png">title</a></li>
            <li><a><img src="2015_images/img.png">title</a></li>
            <li><a><img src="2015_images/img.png">title</a></li>
            <li><a><img src="2015_images/img.png">title</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a onclick="dropdownToggle(event)"><span>Services</span></a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a>item</a></li>
            <li><a>item</a></li>
            <li><a>item</a></li>
            <li><a>item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a onclick="dropdownToggle(event)">     <span>Softwares</span></a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a>item</a></li>
            <li><a>item</a></li>
            <li><a>item</a></li>
            <li><a>item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: -500px;
  background-color: #585859;
  transition: top 0.3s;
  z-index: 1;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    line-height: 65px;
    width: auto;
    position: static;
  }
}
.navbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.navbar li {
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
.dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-open {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(88, 88, 89, 0.7);
  width: 100%;
}
.submenu {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px 0 !important;
}
.submenu li {
  margin: 0 2px;
  flex: 0 0 12%;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

and JS

```
function dropdownToggle(event) {
  var dropdownItem = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("dropdown")[0];
  if (dropdownItem.classList.contains("dropdown-open")) {
    var dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown");
    var arrayLength = dropdowns.length;
     for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        dropdowns[i].classList.remove("dropdown-open");
      }
    }

    else {
      dropdownItem.classList.toggle("dropdown-open");
    }
}
```

I tried on JSFiddle but it is not working so here is a codepen as well.. 
http://codepen.io/nnns/pen/rLvdgE

Comment: Your code is extremely complicated. You could replace "event.target.parentElement.parentElement." with "document."

Comment: No errors it seems to be working fine the only issue is i can't close it when i click on the same item or another one or anywhere,

Comment: i am very new to JS, and i just use the textbook, so it might look old fashion

Comment: The dropdownitem is always the first. So it will check if the first one is open, not if anyone is open

Comment: To close it when clicked anywhere add document.all.body.onclick=function(){...}

Comment: yes i see, but i couldn't figuer out how to check if any is open?

Comment: I rewrite the code. One moment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way will be to put

```
var dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown");
var arrayLength = dropdowns.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    dropdowns[i].classList.remove("dropdown-open");
}
```

in a function and call it at the beginning of your `function dropdownToggle(event)` so like that every time you call your function you close everything and can open what you want.

**EDIT**

Do this:

```
function dropdownToggle(event) {
var dropdownItem =event.target.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("dropdown")[0];
var dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown");
var arrayLength = dropdowns.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    dropdowns[i].classList.remove("dropdown-open");
}
dropdownItem.classList.add("dropdown-open");
}
```

Comment: Why to put a function it into another function?

Comment: Because like that he can use it again later inside his `if (dropdownItem.classList.contains("dropdown-open"))` but that not necessary. The most important is to close every submenu at the beginning and open the wanted one.

Comment: on your new code you create a new function but don't use it. I've edited my post to just use as Copy/past answer. I've made it on your Codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yJjjVL

Comment: Thank you, i am getting it but in this case i can't close the item itself, 
Like if MenuItem1 is open and i click on Menuitem2 then the 1 will close but if i click on Menuitem1 it will not close like it will do nothing

Comment: @Nassif I have updated your code here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yJjjVL now you can change or close the same submenu. Enjoy :)

Comment: Thank you, it is working very fine
what if i need it to close when i click anywhere?

Comment: @Nassif You're welcome! in this case it's a bit more complexe, you have to add a listener on your document to check if your clicked element is on the menu or not. if not we close everything. On http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yJjjVL  I've added the listener, take care I also added an ID to make it more easy on your "navbar". If you click on the title or text it will close. If you open a menu and click on it it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function dropdownToggle(event) {
var dropdownItem = event.target.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("dropdown")[0];    
 dropdownItem.classList.remove("dropdown");
var dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown"); 
var arrayLength = dropdowns.length;   
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
 dropdowns[i].classList.remove("dropdown-open");

}   
   dropdownItem.classList.toggle("dropdown-open");    
 dropdownItem.classList.add("dropdown");
}
```

This removes all dropdown open classes and toggles the  dropdown that is found in the parent(li) of the a.
To close on body click:

```
document.all.body.onclick=dropdownToggle(document.all.body);
```

Comment: Hey Thank you very much,
The problem with this one is i can't close the item when i am clicking on it, it always opens

Comment: And when i am using this code 

<code>document.all.body.onclick=dropdownToggle(document.all.body);</code>

it doesn't work

Comment: <code> is for marking inline code. Use <script> instead

Comment: This code seems to be better but i still can't close the item when i click on it, like if there is another one open then it will close and open its self but if it is open and i click on it it won't close.

Comment: Hmmm. Could you open the console and run it line for line?

Comment: It should remove the dropdown class of the clicked element, hide all other dropdown, add the dropdown class again and toggle the open class

Comment: yes that what it does, but when we add this line `dropdownItem.classList.add("dropdown-open");`
it removes the class and then it adds it again so it looks like it does nothing

Comment: because when the loop runs it removes the dropdown-open class from all the items, so the toggle which we have at the end will act like add because the item doesn't have the dropdown-open class anymore

Comment: Not add("dropdown-open") toggle("dropdown-open")

Comment: It removes the dropdown and adds it again, so that the for loop dont caches him.

Comment: yes i use toggle, but the point is at the start it removes all the open ones, so when it reaches the toggle line it will be close, so the toggle will open it again

Comment: No. I removed the dropdown class from the clicked, so that the for loop does not change it

Comment: See line 3 and the last

Comment: Great, thank you so much, it is working properly now, but still this line isn't working
document.all.body.onclick=dropdownToggle(document.all.body);

Comment: Add a console.log(event) to the dropdownToggle and see if it fires when you click somewhere